# UnityInitializer class is missing when adding awssdk core library in Unity

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net, amazon-gamelift

I was recently trying to add the NET4.5 AWSSDK Core and GameLift libraries to my game in order to use aws GameLift services.

In the tutorials I follow, it says that I need to use the functions within UnityInitializer class that is supposed to be included in the AWSSDK.Core library, but the dlls imported from the NuGet package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Core/ seems to be missing that class (might not be the only thing it's missing)

I've also tried to install the AWS Mobile SDK from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/what-is-unity-plugin.html
which contains another version of the AWSSDK.Core with the UnityInitializer class included, but this led to other issues and does not contain the AWSSDK.GameLift library

I was wondering if anyone else ran into these issues and would know how to work around this issue in order to use GameLift services in a Unity project.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it is needed (maybe an old call), I believe you call the following for Initialization:

```
m_GLClient = new AmazonGameLiftClient(m_Credentials, region); // Client
```